# Oracle retrieve only number in string

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle pl/sql, how do I retrieve only numbers from string.

e.g. 123abc -> 123 (remove alphabet)

e.g. 123*-*abc -> 123 (remove all special characters too)

Comment: Your title in Google -> First result: [Extract number value from string](https://community.oracle.com/thread/598281). 2nd and 3rd results might be helpful too. 4th as well, btw.

Comment: You can use a regular_exp for achiving the same

Comment: I have this string '123ss-21d!28!~' without single quote. I want to make it '1232128'. Why can't you all understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options, but this should work:

```
select regexp_replace('123*-*abc', '[^[:digit:]]', '') from dual
```

This removes all non-digits from the input.

If using in pl/sql, you could do an assignment to a variable:

```
declare
    l_num number;
    l_string varchar2(20) := '123*-*abc';
begin
    l_num := regexp_replace(l_string, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
    dbms_output.put_line('Num is: ' || l_num);
end;
```

Output:

```
Num is: 123
```

Answer (score 3):

```
your_string := regexp_replace(your_string, '\D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select regexp_replace(value, '[A-Za-z]') from dual;
```